# What does *(*int)(nil) = 0 mean in golang?

Tags: go, pointers

I notice there is one line `*(*int)(nil) = 0` in function [`throw`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/panic.go#L1113)

```golang
//go:nosplit
func throw(s string) {
    // Everything throw does should be recursively nosplit so it
    // can be called even when it's unsafe to grow the stack.
    systemstack(func() {
        print("fatal error: ", s, "\n")
    })
    gp := getg()
    if gp.m.throwing == 0 {
        gp.m.throwing = 1
    }
    fatalthrow()
    *(*int)(nil) = 0 // not reached
}
```

What does `*(*int)(nil) = 0` means? and since this line `*(*int)(nil) = 0` could NOT be reached, why it is here? any special usage?

Comment: It is the compiler-internal variant of `panic("unreachable")` .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The line:

```
*(*int)(nil) = 0
```

Tries to dereference a `nil` pointer and assign a value to it, which is always a runtime panic. The code should not reach this line, ever, but if it would anyhow (e.g. a faulty code change in the future), it would panic so the error could be detected and wouldn't go unnoticed.

It's common sense to do something similar in your code too, but with a more obvious "construct" such as `panic("unreachable")`. For example:

```
func sign(a int) string {
    switch {
    case a > 0:
        return "Positive"
    case a < 0:
        return "Negative"
    case a == 0:
        return "Zero"
    default:
        panic("unreachable")
    }
}
```

Note that in this example this is not just to detect errors early, it's also a requirement because to the compiler there would be no guarantee that a return statement would be reached. You could also move the `panic("unreachable")` statement after the `switch` (instead of the `default` branch), it's a matter of taste.

If you would change the above function to not return but print the sign, it would still be a good practice to leave the `default` branch to panic, although it's not a requirement in this variant:

```
func printSign(a int) {
    switch {
    case a > 0:
        fmt.Println("Positive")
    case a < 0:
        fmt.Println("Negative")
    case a == 0:
        fmt.Println("Zero")
    default:
        panic("unreachable")
    }
}
```