# What exactly is this "cast" doing in Golang?

Tags: go, syntax, casting, type-assertion

Can someone point me in the right direction of this Go's syntax :

```
(*int)(nil)
```

If I have a a value of a given type and I want to convert it to, lets say, float64 I can do this :

```
var num int = 65
fnum := float64(num)
```

If I have an interface and I want to "cast it" to some type I can do this :

```
func main() {
    concretevalue := dosomething("hello!")
    fmt.Printf("%T : %v", concretevalue, concretevalue)
}

func dosomething( v interface{} ) string {
    return v.(string)
}
```

Where does the **(*int)(nil)** fit? How can I get information about this specific syntax?

Comment: it declares a `nil` pointer to a value of type `int`.

Comment: The expression `(*int)(nil)` [converts](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the untyped value `nil` to a `*int`.  The parenthesis  in `(*int)` group the '*` with the `int`.

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751440/what-does-intnil-0-mean-in-golang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a type-conversion, same as `float64(num)`, however, because the converted type is a pointer, you need extra parentheses, because otherwise *int(nil) would mean converting `nil` to int, and then dereferencing it.